# How to get the next button in adaptive card similar to that in hero card

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards

I'm trying to replicate features of hero card in adaptive cards. Specifically speaking, in hero card when the number of options are lengthy, we get the next button which takes us to the next card showing rest of the options. How can I create similar feature in adaptive cards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this feature is not particularly associated with adaptive cards. This feature is called Carousel and can be built in JSON using the tag `"attachements":[]`
In attachments you create various adaptive cards that is displayed as a carousel. I'll put a sample code for reference.

[JSON Content](https://github.com/matthidinger/ContosoScubaBot/blob/master/Cards/1-Schools.JSON)